# How to avoid chrome external dialog in WebdriverIO testing

Tags: google-chrome, modal-dialog, webdriver-io

[Chrome external protocol dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5drKO.png%5C)

The first step of the e2e WebdriverIO test is to goto the login page. But the dialog stopped the test case from going further. I didn't find a way to either close the dialog using WebdriverIO or disable the dialog. Any one can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add this to your `wdio.conf` file

```
  "capabilities": [
    {
      ...
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
        "args": [
          "disable-infobars",
          "disable-popup-blocking",
          "disable-notifications"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

or check this link: [wdio github issue](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/2718)

Answer (score 0):

add this to wdio.conf file. works fine for me in chrome 117

```js
capabilities: [{
        browserName: 'chrome',
        'goog:chromeOptions': {
            'excludeSwitches': ['enable-automation']
        }
    }],
```